# Flutter: Keeping a card widget with dynamic text the same size

Tags: flutter

I have a Card widget in my app that displays the value of a timer. My issue is that because  the font is not monospaced, the width of widget changes each second. How do I avoid this? Do I just guess a fixed number of pixels for the Card width that's big enough to always fit the value? or is there a better way to do this?

Code for the widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ValueDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final String value;

  const ValueDisplay(this.value, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        side: BorderSide(
          width: 5,
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
        child: Text(
          value,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'RobotoSlab',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Photo of the widget:
[image: Picture of the described widget]

Comment: One option is to use a monospaced font. Other is to have a fixed width to fit the largest (probably 99:99:99), center the text and have different paddings at the left and right. Or you can adjust the font size automatically with `FittedBox` widget to fit always.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer! Is there an easy way in code to calculate the pixel width of a String? Or do I need to render the 99:99:99 myself and inspect the element to check the width?

Comment: It can be difficult, because different phones can render it differently, even the user can adjust the font size in the phone settings which might impact the size. I would experimentally find a good-looking size and use the [`FittedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) widget.